# Dill installed - throwing error that part of the module is missing

Tags: python, pickle, dill

I'm writing code in a Jupyter Notebook that involves cleaning and analyzing a large amount of consumer data. I'm trying to use dill to save the dataframes with thousands of rows so I don't have to run the code every time I want to make an adjustment, so dill seems like the perfect package to do so... Except I'm getting this error when attempting to pickle the notebook:

```
AttributeError: module 'dill' has no attribute 'dump_session'
```

Let me know if the program code is necessary - I don't think it should make a difference. The imports are:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dill
import scipy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from __future__ import division
from collections import OrderedDict
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
pd.options.display.max_columns = None
```

and when I run this code I get the error from above:

```
dill.dump_session('recengine.db')
```

Is there another package that's interfering with dill's use of pickle vs. cpickle?

Comment: That looks like you've got a `dill.py` file shadowing the actual module.  Try `import dill; print(dill.__file__)` to find out where it is.

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'dill' has no attribute '__file__'` well that's problematic... I've installed `dill` so this comes with a surprise

Comment: python -c "from dill import dump_session"?

Comment: now getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dill'`
I'm using Anaconda Navigator to launch my notebook - would I have to install dill differently in that case?